# What is the name of this C# syntax?

Tags: c#, syntax, object-initializers

In C#, you can do something like this:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass () {
    SomeProperty = someValue
};
```

What is this syntax called?

Comment: BTW, you don't need the parentheses `()`, if they are not supplied the parameter-less constructor will be invoked by default.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Object initializer](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/09/09/c-3-0-features-object-initializers.aspx) is the name.

Comment: Wouldn't that be more like "Object initializer the name is. Hmmph! Much to learn you have."

Comment: If so smart Yoda is, right order words in his sentences Yoda puts not why?

Comment: If I remember my Star Wars mythos correctly, Yoda spoke grammatically correct english up until the day he read *Chapter 7: Wisdom You Have Not, But Sound Like It You Will* of the book *Jedi Grammer Hacks: You May Have The Force, But Your Words Are Not Forceful*.   

...or I just made that up.